# Why some .NET component has no accessible class / methods?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

For example, I'm trying to use the System.Threading.Timer in NAV, but selecting the assembly returns empty result like shown below:

[image: Threading.Timer has no usable class]

Is this by design, or do I need to do something else first before I am able to use the methods inside Threading.Timer component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use .NET class in NAV is to lookup the assembly, where it is located, on the MSDN page for this class.

For example, in case of System.Threading.Timer, it is located in mscorlib library:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

`Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)`

Answer (score 0):

.NET decompilers like dotPeek also don't show any types when opening that particular DLL. Are you sure you want to use this library? What are you trying to achieve?

If you just need a timer, you may want to consider using Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.PingPong.dll, which ships with NAV.